# Bootstrap twitter can't see correctly the example "sign-in"

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a basic example of Bootstrap Twitter ([sign-in example](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)). In the link you can see the code of the example.

I copy-paste code in my IDE (NetBeans) replacing this line:

```
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for this one, which indicate where Bootstrap is in my pc:

```
<link href="MEDIA/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But if I run that sample I see this web instead of the nice original of the example:

[image]

I think I should be seen the same result as in the example, don't I?
Why am I getting this result?

Thanks for any tip!

**EDIT 2:** @mohsin.mr you're right (what a stupid mistake) thanks for that! I was having the signin.css on another directory, however now I have a similar result, but not the same as in the example. The button looks different and the textbox's length are shorter than the button's length.

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is the code I'm running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="MEDIA/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that you might be missing some parent `div`. But please show your complete code for better understanding

Comment: Are you sure that **signin.css** placed in same folder where this HTML file exists?

Comment: @mohsin.mr you were right. I fixed that problem. I realize that the signin.css isn't the same as in the example, because I must edit it in order to set the length of the pass and mail.

Comment: Another thing I just realized is that it isn't responsive, if I play with the windows's size it remains unresponsive :(

Comment: can you please vote up my answer and also choose it as correct one to help other viewers to know about the issue you were experiencing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire code is looking correct. Now the only reason due to which you experiencing this issue is to linking **signin.css** because it seems the bootstrap css file is also importing correctly and pattern of code is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the following custom CSS for center align the div

```
.form-signin {
max-width: 330px;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

see the working [fiddle](http://bootply.com/88767)